# How to send mail to a specified user whose email data collected from form in formsflow.ai?

Tags: formsflow.ai

I am using the latest version of [formsflow.ai](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai) and I want to send an email to a person whose data was collected from the form. I need to know how to create the workflow to send emails to a specific person whose data is dynamically collected from the form in formsflow.ai.

I am expecting to dynamically send mail to users whose data is collected from a form instead of keycloak users

Answer (score 5):

step 1: Create your form in form Design with a form component say email as form data API Key.[image: form design]

step 2: Create workflow in camunda modeler to send the email
[image: workflow]
in order to get the form data we need to use the following listener[FormDataPipelineListener](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/blob/master/forms-flow-bpm/starter-examples/listeners/formbpmdatapipeline-readme.md)
use the following screenshot for reference [image: Refer Image]
And after that, I am using the execution listener to get the variable email and pass them to dmn
[image: Execution listner]
use the following dmn for reference [image: Dmn diagram]
step 3: use email attribute listener to send the mail
[image: Email attribute Listner]
[image: Reference]
[image: Reference]
[image: Reference]